# How to understand this java extend syntax with angular bracket and letter I

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

How should I understand this java class syntax? What are must following rules when extending `AbstractA`?

`public abstract class AbstractA<I extends AbstractB> extends AbstractC<I>{}`

The following are my understandings:

Assume "A" is subclass of `AbstractA`, "B" is subclass of `AbstractB`.

1. `AbstractA` has class holder `I`.
2. `A extends AbstractA<I>`, where `I` could be `AbstractB` itself, or abstract class B, or regular B.
3. Both A and I placeholder is also children of `AbstractC`.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You are using some terminology that seems to be not the standard in Java, such as "class holder" and "placeholder". Can you explain what they mean? Also, what do you mean by `or abstract class B, or regular B`? Is `B` abstract or concrete?

Comment: I am new to java so the term I am using might be incorrect. Should class holder be called temporary data type? I thought it is a placeholder that require to be replaced with a different class in subclass inheritance.

Comment: No, it's not a placeholder. Read more about Java generics. Did the duplicate help?